# How to save clusters files in google colab into Google Drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have `cluster_Model` in `colab` and my model make 220 `CSV` file's and I want to automatically saved into my `google Drive`
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't find the best way to do that, but this is work for me

```
from google.colab import files

for k in range(211, 221):
    fileName = 'cluster'+ str(k) +'.csv' // this is the file name
    files.download(fileName)
```